# Regexprep's starting point

Tags: regex, string, matlab

I have a string `S` and a pattern `P` (in Matlab). I want to find all the appearances of `P` in `S` and shorten each of them using `regexprep`. But I want to do it by `O(n)`. It will be solved if I know how to pass to `regexprep`, what is the position in 'S' to start the search from.

Here is my awkward approach. I maintain this position `p` in memory and assign it for every iteration. Then I launch `regexprep` this way:

```
s = strcat(s(1:p),regexprep(s((p+1):length(s)),'P','f(P)','once');
```

Is there any easier approach?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `regexprep` already do that?

```
>> S = 'g3dd4e5t67y8';
>> P = '[a-z][0-9]';
>> R = '*';
>> result = regexprep(S,P,R)
result =
*d***7*
```

Comment: I process every entry of P. Your R must be the function of P.